# Extracting jpg/jpeg files from multiple .zip files

Tags: zip

I have a folder with over 200 `.zip` files. In each of these files there is only one folder with several types of archives in it (sometimes, this folder is missing). Among them, I want to extract only the `.jpg` or `.jpeg` file. The estructure of the `zip` file is:

```
AAAA-99999-2015.zip
     AAAA-99999-2015 (optional)
          AAAA-99999-2015.jpg (or .jpeg)
          AAAA-99999-2015.prj
          AAAA-99999-2015.ecw
          readme.txt
```

¿How can I automate this task without manually have to open all these 200 archives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
find . -type f -iname \*zip -print0 | xargs -0 --max-args=1 --replace unzip {} \*.jpg \*.jpeg
```

This would look in the current folder and sub-folders for files called "*.zip", then for each one of them, individually (`--max-args=1`) the command `unzip` is called, appending `\*.jpg \*.jpeg`, thereby selecting the files to extract.

(If we select both `*.jpeg` and `*.jpg` files and some of these do not exist `unzip` may warn us about that. This can be safely ignored.)

If you wish to test what happens first, insert an `echo`:

```
find . -type f -iname \*zip -print0 | xargs -0 --max-args=1 --replace echo unzip {} \*.jpg \*.jpeg
```

If you with to extract all files in the current folder, irrespective of where they are inside the ZIP file, add the `-j` option to `unzip`:

```
find . -type f -iname \*zip -print0 | xargs -0 --max-args=1 --replace unzip -j {} \*.jpg \*.jpeg
```

You can also add a target folder by using `-d foldername` after the `-j`.

Comment: Thanks. One minor problem with this solution is that I do not get the `.jpg` or `.jpeg` file, but a folder with the wanted files if in the `.zip` those files were inside a folder. I know how to collect then all the image files, but there is a way of doing this in the previous command?

Comment: @fich OK, I updated my answer accordingly.